# How can I make publish and subscribe in one file?

Tags: rabbitmq, elixir

I want to make easy application with sending messages (rabbitmq). When run program I want to write messages and receive it (in same console). So how can I write a method "subcribe" which will be running all the time(after starting program) and waiting to receive message? and at same time of course i should be able to write a message

Comment: I'm also very curious about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a supervised app (mix new my_app --sup ).
You implement two GenServer, one for receiving (MyApp.Reader) and the other one for sending (MyApp.Writer). You add both GenServer as worker in your supervisor spec.

I guess your RabbitMQ adapter (never used it with elixir so you'll have to double check) will also be supervised. Name it, and pass its name to both GenServer init method (via the args you pass when declaring your workers for example)

You can also implement your API for the writer directly in MyApp. Something like:

```
  def send(message) do
    GenServer.cast(:name_of_writer, $message)
  end
```

You'll then be able to do: `MyApp.send("some message")`

Your receiver worker, would on its side, receive all messages, and print them to the CLi, either using inspect or the Logger module

Have a look at [the GenServer docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html), there is some code example that will help you.